# dynamically override property to object returned by Mock() spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I am trying to test an object with Spock that inherits a readonly id, but in order to do the testing I need to set a value. I have verified with the hasProperty that the property exists during runtime. What I have tried is this:

```
def au = Mock(AisUser)
au.id >> 2L
```

I can't do it with metaClass because it's a mock. Is there any other way I can dynamically override the property? Perhaps remove it from the object and then reinsert dynamically?

Comment: Edit: def au = Mock(AisUser); au.id >> 2L;

Comment: Is the `id` property declared in the `AisUser` class, or is it a dynamic property?

Comment: It's a property inherited by the AisUser.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of messing around with the code i figured it out. An instance of the AisUser was returned every time the static method retrieveCurrentAisUser was called. But i was dynamically adding that static method in my setup block. So i figured since i am declaring a closure and i have access to the variables of the rest of the block I'll just make an instance of the AisUser which i will return every time the closure is executed and i wil put a Spy on that instance so that i can verify it's behaviour. And also i add dynamically the id with metaprogramming. Probably because i don't call mockDomain on AisUser it doesn't enforce the readonly attribute, but I'm not sure why it let's me do it, but it works. So this is the code:

```
def au = Spy(AisUser)
SecurityUtil.metaClass.'static'.retrieveCurrentAisUser = { boolean param ->
    au.id >> 1L
    return au;
}
```

and in the then block i can do this:

```
1 * au.getProperty('id')
```